# AppHarbor Web.config transform error

Tags: settings, appharbor, web-config-transform

I have web.config file that overrides items in Settings file like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MvcApplication.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="FacebookUrlAuth" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://URL1.com</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="GoogleUrlAuth" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://URL2.com</value>
      </setting>
    </MvcApplication.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

And I have web.release.config that transforms these settings:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <applicationSettings>
    <MvcApplication.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="FacebookUrlAuth" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <value>http://AlternativeUrl1.com</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="GoogleUrlAuth" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <value>http://AlternativeUrl2.com</value>
      </setting>
    </MvcApplication.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

When I publish solution in Release configuration it works properly (I mean only url's are become different from web.config)

But when Appharbor publishes the application I get a runtime error from the page I use `@Settings.Default.FacebookUrlAuth`

with the following details:

**Unrecognized element 'setting'. (D:\websites\45\31968\17022\0x0001_PublishedWebsites\MVC.Web\web.config line 73)**

When I comment all transformation rules, AppHarbor takes these properties from my default web.config and everything works ok.
Is it an issue on the AppHarbor side?

Comment: friism: You was absolutely right! For some reason Appharbor transforms my config in  a wrong way. Please come out to recive a +1

Comment: I have figured out the trouble. As friism said and then deleted his solution: "You can't have multiple setting elements. The error is probably not related to the transformation." and he provided the link to the explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/02/16/system-configuration-configurationerrosexception-unrecognized-element-setting-and-other-unrecognized-elements.aspx I have read the exactely web.config from the AppHarbor hosting and figured out that after the transformation the settings are one lined. So, I think it's a AppHarbor bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can't have multiple `setting` elements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/02/16/system-configuration-configurationerrosexception-unrecognized-element-setting-and-other-unrecognized-elements.aspx). The error is probably not related to the transformation.

Comment: Please see the way my settings are written. They are not in one line.

Comment: You was right! The final trouble was bacause it transforms to one lined setting

Comment: @Anubis, I'm surprised you got this working - I am having some problems even getting the transformations executing as described here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14739099/171810, Any ideas?